# Not supporting hover variable with hyphen in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

For debugging Cobol program using vscode extension I have extended debug extension protocol. I have variables with hyphen in my **cobol** program e.g: emp-salary.
I have set the flag *supportsEvaluateForHovers* to **true**.
While debugging I am trying to hover this kind of variable but, value I am getting inside *evaluateRequest* method is NOT considering this as complete one variable name and just returning hyphen separated part of variable. For example out of **emp-salary** I do mouse hover over **emp** it is returning emp only.

My expectation is it shall return emp-salary as it is single variable name.

What exact changes I will need to implement in my code so it will consider hyphen separated variable as one variable?

Comment: Tejashree has also opened issue with microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node/issues/259

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" flag under Debugging. This worked for me today using VS 2019.